# How do I create/make an album in a named folder in OSX Photos with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, photos

I am looking for a solution whereby I can run an AppleScript locally to take a bunch of photos that are in Smart Folders in OSX Photos app and put them in non-smart equivalents. I found a script that largely does this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Photos"
        get folder "Managing the library"
        set smartAlb to album "Measurements"
        set regAlbName to "Measurements-Static"
        tell album regAlbName to if exists then delete
        set regAlb to make new album named regAlbName
        add (get media items of smartAlb) to regAlb
    end tell
end run
```

However, while I can set the folder of where to get the info from, the new album is created at the top level in Photos. All I am after is a tweak to the code shown to ensure that the new album is created in the same folder (currently called 'Managing the Library'). I've tried all sorts but I am not a regular AppleScript user, and couldn't find an answer online.

Appreciate any help people can provide :)

Comment: For info, my reason for doing this is so that these non Smart albums will sync to iCloud Photo Library and also be available then in iOS devices (which currently cannot access Smart Albums). Thanks

Comment: Solution I wanted to adapt was on here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7560340?start=0&tstart=0

I aim to have mine run automatically via the calendar as per this suggestion too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the location information where to create the new folder. Instead of just getting the folder `Managing the library` assign the reference to a variable and pass it in the `make new album` line.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Photos"
        set manageFolder to folder "Managing the library"
        set smartAlb to album "Measurements"
        set regAlbName to "Measurements-Static"
        tell album regAlbName to if exists then delete
        set regAlb to make new album named regAlbName at manageFolder
        add (get media items of smartAlb) to regAlb
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's worked great, but I'm wondering if I could get it working ever so slightly differently. If I wanted to have two subfolders, like so:

Managing the Library/Smart Albums
Managing the Library/Manual Albums

And have the script copy from smart to Manual (jump up a level then back down), is this possible too?

Comment: You can reference folders by `folder "foo" of folder "bar"` or albums by `album "foo" of folder "bar"` relating to the top level.